# Using pre-trained MaltParser model with NLTK

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

Can anyone tell me how to use a pre-trained MaltParser model (http://maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.html) in nltk.parse.malt? The only option seems to be to train from a file (If anyone could point me in the direction of a good, publicly available training file, that would be great, too).

Answer (score 3):

The MaltParser interface in older versions of NLTK used to hardcode the path to the model. This was fixed in commit [e9e443](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/e9e4431f0f7697c7cf633997539d85d29c21c79f). You can now do the following:

```
maltparser = MaltParser(mco="/path/to/your/model.mco")
```

As of this writing, easy_install and pip still install a version of NLTK that doesn't include this fix (2.0.1rc4). If you cannot afford switching to a bleeding edge version, you could use the following hack:

```
maltparser = MaltParser()
maltparser.mco = "/path/to/your/model.mco"
```

Pre-trained models can be found on [MaltParser's official website](http://maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.html).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding using pretrained model - 
It seems this has been (and it seems still to be) an open subject in the nltk dev forum:
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/145

From what I understand you can do it via setting some internal variable:

> "And while you can manually set the mco field on the object, that's not exposed in the
>   API, 
>   and a user who hasn't dug into the code wouldn't know that."

Yet I was unable to find the specific place to do this.

Regarding getting a pretrained model - I am referring you to this topic on SO:

[Does NLTK have a tool for dependency parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125926/does-nltk-have-a-tool-for-dependency-parsing)