# NLP convert bracket notation to dependency tree

Tags: python, nlp, dependency-parsing

Given a bracket notation  of constituent words, is there a way to convert it into its dependency tree?

```
[S [NP [Proper-Noun John]][VP [Verb saw][NP [Proper-Noun Mary]][PP [Preposition with][NP [Determiner a][Noun telescope]]]]]
```

into

```
nsubj(saw-2, John-1)
root(ROOT-0, saw-2)
dobj(saw-2, Mary-3)
case(telescope-6, with-4)
det(telescope-6, a-5)
nmod(saw-2, telescope-6)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many language/representation-specific decisions and heuristics involved in this kind of conversion, so you're not going to find any standard language-independent conversion tools. If you're working with PTB-style English trees there are several existing converters:

- There's the one developed for the Stanford parser ([edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/EnglishGrammaticalStructure.html)), which produces the kind of output you have above, described in their [FAQ](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#s). (See also a related question: [Stanford Dependencies Conversion Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846355/stanford-dependencies-conversion-tool).)
- There's also an older very PTB-specific [LTH Constituent-to-Dependency Conversion Tool for Penn-style Treebanks](http://nlp.cs.lth.se/software/treebank_converter/), which produces CoNLL 2008-style output.

Your example doesn't look like a standard PTB tree so you might need to adapt an existing converter, in which case the Stanford converter is probably a good starting point.

Comment: So to get SVO triples as well, you need dependency parsing? Or is possible to extract this info from the above output only?

Comment: No, the dependency relations are extracted from a constituent parse tree similar to the one above. Take a look at the Stanford parser code in edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure and edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalRelations. EnglishGrammaticalRelations shows the kind of tree patterns that are used to find relations like nsubj. You can see that it's very English/PTB-specific and there are a lot of heuristics.